# How Datastore write operation is calculated(total number of write)for simple and complex query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an app engine project with datastore(creating our database),

As per the information give in this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing) total number of read write operation is listed for different case(Insert ,update and delete),but i am confused how write operation is calculated for modifying index and composite index.

we have below Case scenario in which we have to calculate number of write operation

1 >> Datastore query requires filtering based on single property no complex query `[no index defined in  datastore-indexes.xml file]`

as per example `“SELECT * FROM MESSAGE AS MESSAGE ORDER BY timestamp  desc"`

2>> Datastore query requires filtering based on single property no complex query `[index defined on one property in  datastore-indexes.xml file ]`
as per example `“SELECT * FROM MESSAGE AS MESSAGE ORDER BY timestamp  desc"`

3>> Datastore query requires filtering based on  complex query `[index defined for complex query defind in datastore-indexes.xml file ]`
 as per example "“SELECT * FROM MESSAGE AS MESSAGE WHERE req_id="xyz123" ORDER BY timestamp  desc"

> > Note::for example purpose i have taken this statement “SELECT * FROM MESSAGE AS MESSAGE ORDER BY timestamp  desc".This jpql query makes a get(1 read operation) http request in order to retrieve data from datastore.

Question

> For above case scenario  how  New Entity Put  write operation  will be
>   counted ?[ New Entity Put  " 2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property
>   value + 1 write per composite index value"]

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entities with single-valued properties, writing a new entity requires the following writes:

- 1 for the entity itself
- 1 for the `EntitiesByKind` index
- 2 for each indexed property
- 1 for each composite index

So for your examples:

1. 1 + 1 + 2*(number of indexed properties)
2. This is actually the same as #1; there's no need to define single-property indexes in `datastore-indexes.xml` as these are included automatically.
3. 1 + 1 + 2*(number of indexed properties) + 1

Here's [more information](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Understanding_write_costs) on Datastore write costs.

Comment: thank you vary much for clarifying my doubt!!!Information given on the link you have provided is really helpful!!!!

Comment: i have doubt regarding number of indexed property,say i have 5 property auto indexed than also consider as index property means for 1. 1+1+2*(5)=12 write count???

Comment: That's correct, an entity with five indexed properties (and no composite indexes) will cost 12 writes. Note that when you modify an entity, only the changed indexes count as writes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

1. 2 + 2 * n(number of indexed property: at least 1, timestamp) + 0
2. 2 + 2 * n(number of indexed property: at least 1, timestamp) + 1(wrong. 0 is right)
3. 2 + 2 * n(number of indexed property: at least 2, req_id, timestamp) + 1

Comment: Ed Davisson's answer is right. The single index in `index.yaml` makes error creating a composite index. I have never tested it before. :)